# Use coalesce to return first non-empty value from 2 tablea

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have 2 tables in my Postgres db. Each of them has a URL column that I want to query and return the first non-empty value. 
Table

```
test1 
id  name   url 

test2 
id   address url
```

I have the `id` as an input. How can I write a query to coalesce the latest available url for any id ?

```
test 1
ID   name         url 
1     A           null     
2     B           abc.com
3     C           xyz.com

test 2
ID   address         url 
1     X            return.com     
2     Y            null
3     Z            efg.com
```

After the coalesce I expect return.com to be returned for `id = 1`
By latest available URL I mean the first non-null entry.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. Also, how do you define the *latestl available url?

Comment: Thanks for the sample data. But you would still need to explain how to order the records (ie define what is the *latest* record). Which column defines the ordering? By default there is no ordering in SQL tables.

Comment: @GMB - Ignore the latest available for now. I want to write a coalesce to return `return.com` in this case since its the first non-empty url for id=1, that would be good enough.

Comment: So why exactly would you get `return.com` from table `test 2` instead of `abc.com` from table `test 1`? They both have `id = 1`. You used the term "first" again without specifying the ordering criteria.

Comment: I updated the tables. So now `id=1` has just one entry in each table. I would like to run coalesce to return `return.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it's hard to determine what "latest" and "first" mean, as `COALESCE` does not know how to distinguish that (basically, you have to define the priority).  If your example seeks `return.com`, then the proper syntax is:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.url,a.url) FROM test_1 a JOIN test2 a ON a.id=b.id WHERE a.id=1
```

So in this example, you will always show `b.url` as long as it is not null.  If you want it to dynamically prioritize `a.url` and `b.url` based on some time-based criteria, you'll need to write a `plpgsql` function or do some convoluted array nesting and string concatenation (or I'd want to see some other experts show off their chops here)

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thanks @richyen. Just wanted to make sure that `return.com` could be in test 1 and test 2 could have null for id=1. I'll try the above and see if it will work for both cases.